# Field weakening effect on stator voltage

Tags: pmsm

In case of field weakening of PMSM, we weaken the rotor flux along d-axis to increase speed. I sort of understand the fact that the motor consumes id and hence iq reduces since there is a current limited curve ([enter link description here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/examples/mcb/win64/xxmcb_mtpa_charac.png)) due to inverter current limit. Likewise is there a limit on voltage applied to the stator from inverter? I guess, there should be due to new back emf due to reduced flux, but cannot reason out further. I am unable to search for good articles on this, and I hope someone can point me in right direction.

Comment: The following article may have some useful information. It also contains a huge number of references, but getting access to them my be difficult. https://krex.k-state.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2097/1507/JamesMevey2009.pdf;jsessionid=8E8362318656BD345489321F83C5752C?sequence=1 posted elsewhere by @Brian Drummond

Comment: The torque reduces due to lower total excitation ((id_magnet_equivalent - id) x iq), it would reduce even if motor and inverter could sustain higher limit currents. Note that in PMSM the id should be negative, only. Due to lower total excitation, the BEMF voltage is lower so it can spin at higher rpms, where V_applied = V_bemf. V_applied can't be higher than rectified voltage from mains.